Assigning a binary value to data for a box plot in R?
Very new beginner to R and data visualization in general, here. I'm trying to create a boxplot in R that illustrates the relationship between body temperature and where an animal was located. I have the data aligned like so:
liz. temp sub on
1    23.5 hum  y
1    23.1 nat  n
2    22.8 hum  y
2    22.1 nat  n

"liz." stands for lizard, "temp" is the temperature of the substrate (sub), and "on" is indicating which substrate the lizard was positioned on.
Ex: y means the lizard had a body temp of 23.5 C and found on a human made substrate. The next row indicates the next random natural substrate available (and its temperature) to that lizard within a set distance.
So far I have coded the following:
lizandsubtemp<- data.frame('liz'=data$liz., 'subtemp'=data$temp, 'subpos'=data$sub, **'bodytemp'= )**
lizandsubtemp

How should I frame the data so that 'body temp' is the value for the temperature in the y row?
Side note: I apologize for the lack of "dput()". If anyone has tips on how to do this for future questions I'm sure I'll have that would also be incredibly helpful. Thank you! This Stack overflow link was not clear enough for this beginners.
lizandsubtemp <- data.frame('liz'=data$liz., 'subtemp'=data$temp, 'subpos'=data$sub, 'bodytemp'=binary_var=data$on)
lizandsubtemp

gave me this (understandable) error code:

Error: unexpected '=' in "lizandsubtemp<- data.frame('liz'=data$liz.,
'subtemp'=data$temp, 'subpos'=data$sub, 'bodytemp'=binary_var="


Could you just do subset(data, on == "y")?

dput(data). Copy and paste the output, put inside code chunk. Hit "Save" button.

data <- data.frame(liz=c(1,1,2,2), temp=c(23.5,23.1,22.8,22.1), sub=c("hum","nat","hum","nat"), on=c("y","n","y","n"))
data[data$on == "y",]
boxplot(temp~on, data)

